# Drive cloning with Rsync

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, clone

I would like to mirror (clone) my TV harddrive to my TVbackup harddrive daily. I don’t want to use RAID, and currently, both drives are in the same computer (this will change in the future).

In order to do this I want to setup Rsync because apparently this is best, and trigger it with a cron operation. I have no experience with this but if I have the following setup:

**Source:**
/media/tv

**Backup:**
/media/tvbackup

Is this the best command to use?

```
rsync -ax --delete --force media/tv/ media/tvbackup
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of the target disk, I would use

```
rsync -ax --delete-first --force media/tv media/tvbackup
```

as this will ensure that no longer existing files are removed so that there should in theory always be enough place for the copy operations.

Depending on the size of the target disk, if the backup disk is larger, you might also have a look at `rsnapshot` which keeps multiple generations of a backup using hardlinks on the target drive. `rsnapshot` uses `rsync` internally.